# How to reduce the log verbosity about template instantiation

Tags: compiler-errors, d, dmd

For a single error (ie a missing semicolon/backet) I get about 250 lines of log which says `Error instantiating template...`. Which is not related to the error. I'd like those not to be displayed anymore. How-to ?

Comment: The general solution is to just ignore anything past the first few dozen lines of output. The `head` utility does this rather well.

Comment: ok I get it, the `head` utility is a subset of `brain`...

Comment: http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?head  similar programs exist for non-posix OSes.

Comment: My bad...Thx for teaching me this btw.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is caused by [DMD bug 7904](http://d.puremagic.com/issues/show_bug.cgi?id=7904).

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a switch for less verbose compiler messages, however if you get really big diagnostics like that you should file it as a bug in [bugzilla](http://d.puremagic.com/issues/enter_bug.cgi?product=D).

Comment: the compiler just seems to give up when it sees an error, but keeps trucking on through the template instantiations and spews a crapload of errors. It came up a few dmd versions ago and hasn't been fixed yet. Really annoying but not a showstopper...

Answer (score 1):

Yes, please submit that to http://d.puremagic.com/issues so we can take a look - thanks!